# Genomic Primer Database - Using an excel function to extract numbers from genetic test and check if it matches primer location

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a genomic database with tests that need to be completed and I would like to write a function to see if the genetic primer matches the test in question.

Tests are usually in format of gene name (BRCA1) genomic position (c.404) then the nucleotide change (G>C)

We then have Primers in the format of: gene name + exon (BRCA1ex10) from a pull down menu that will bring in the genetic location which covers c.3640 to c. 4096

The tables will look like the following:

| TEST | Primer | Primer location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RAD51C c.404G>C | RAD51Cex02 | c.146 to c.405 |
| BRCA1 c.3869_3870delAA | BRCA1ex10-12 | c.3640 to c.4096 |
| FLCN c.1490_1491delTG | FLCNex12-13 | c.1301 to c.1538 |
| CHEK2 c.433C>T | CHEK2ex03ex04 | c.320 to c.592 |

I'm trying to pull out the first number only from the "TEST" column and wrote the following function

=MID(LEFT(H10,FIND({">","_","d","i"},H10)-2),FIND("c.",H10)+2,LEN(H10))

Since genetic changes will always have one of the following ">","_","d","i". This function returned the following values

| Genetic Position |
| --- |
| 404 |
| #Value |
| #Value |
| 433 |

This function only seems to work for those genetic changes with the ">" character.

Once I have the genetic position I think I will be able to check if it is between the two numbers in the primer location quite easily. Thanks for the help

Comment: Previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73549279/cross-referencing-two-excel-workbooks-using-excel-or-vba-for-a-genetics-problem but it looks like you didn't respond to any of the comments there.  Seems like using regex in a VBA UDF would be the best approach here: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/

Comment: Please format as code your formulas

Answer (score 0):

Your formula results in an array of 4 results per row. Which is visible if you have access to Office 365 (column K-N in picture below):

[image]

In `P10` I used your formula as index and matched to the first result being a number (`N()` function is used because `MID()` returns text if you don't convert it to number):

```
=INDEX(MID(LEFT(H10,FIND({">","_","d","i"},H10)-2),FIND("c.",H10)+2,LEN(H10)),MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(N(MID(LEFT(H10,FIND({">","_","d","i"},H10)-2),FIND("c.",H10)+2,LEN(H10)))),0))
```

This requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` in older Excel versions.